# C++: Does the order of using declaration and directive affect the selection?

Tags: c++, using

Below is the sample code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


namespace A {
    void f() { cout << "a" << endl; }
}
namespace B {
    void f() { cout << "b" << endl; }
}
namespace C {
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
    using A::f;
}
namespace D {
    using A::f;
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
}
int main()
{
    C::f();
    D::f();
}
```

This prints "a" twice when I try in Visual Studio 2015, is this behavior defined by standard or is this implementation specific?

Comment: While this is a perfectly valid language lawyer question, I hope you don't follow this practice in creating real world applications.

Comment: @RSahu too late, I checked-in some code of this sort into some repo

Comment: It's never too late to improve your code :)

Comment: @pasha run... they're loading the shotgun now ... you can still get out of there

Comment: @UKMonkey ....yeah <*nervous laughing*>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defined by the standard (things like this always are). The key thing to realize, is that your various `using namespace` lines do not have any effect on your program.

`using namespace Foo` is a "using directive", which affects name lookup which is performed by code within the scope. That is, if some later function in your `namespace C {}` block tried to find some object named `foo`, `A` and `B` would be among the places that the compiler would search to find a `foo`. In contrast, it wouldn't change where the compiler would look if later code referred to `C::foo`. The order of two consecutive `using namespace`s in a single block is immaterial, since each one has full effect until the end of the block.

The reason you're able to find an `f` in `C` or `D` is the "using declaration" `using A::f`. A using-declaration, unlike a using-directive, has the effect of injecting a name into a scope, such that other code can refer to the name as being within that scope.

Comment: for anyone checking this answer, please have a look at idmean's answer, it addresses little more on the same topic

Answer (score 4):

The following two paragraphs from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) should explain the behavior:

> Using-directive [`using namespace A;`] does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears (unlike the using-declaration [`using A::f;`]), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.
>
> Using-directives are transitive for the purposes of unqualified lookup: if a scope contains a using-directive that nominates a namespace-name, which itself contains using-directive for some namespace-name-2, the effect is as if the using directives from the second namespace appear within the first. The order in which these transitive namespaces occur does not influence name lookup.

Simply put: `using A::f;` is as if you declared the function in this namespace. `using namespace A;` just causes typename lookup to behave as if the current namespace (`C` or `D`) in your case were namespaces within `A`.

This is similar to how

```
namespace A {
    void f() { cout << "a" << endl; }

    namespace B {
        void f() { cout << "b" << endl; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        void f() { cout << "b" << endl; }
    }

    void f() { cout << "a" << endl; }
}
```

are equivalent.